# struts property tag not working with <img src> tag in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am trying to display image files on a JSP page using a JavaBean and Struts 2 by retrieving path from the database. The `<img>` tag is not recognizing the image path.

When I try to display the path its shows correct path using this line :

```
<s:property value='%{path}'/>
<s:property value='#{path}'/>

# Displays

C:\Users\Admin\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\File_Demo\1011_1.png
```

Nothing is displayed when written this statement with the `<img>` tag.

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags"  prefix="s"%>
<html>
  <body>
    <img alt=":p" src="<s:property value='%{path}'/>"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why `%{path}` and not `${path}`

Comment: Images are served relative to your app, or by putting them in a known location and either streaming them from an action or servlet, or by mapping a server location to that path, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first check in the rendered page that the img tag actually contains the right path parameter (you said you tried to print it out but better dbl check). (View source, or in Firefox, right clikc and inspect element).

But, the main problme is your actual path. From the question it is an absolute path to some dir on your C: drive. But it is not your browser that fetches that file directly from the drive but it is the server that serves it, so your server (tomcat I guess ??) needs to be able to resolve the path to particular file. Normally, the web server uses relative paths not absolute ones so it will not be able to serve the whole content of your machine.

In webapp it is will be files relative to your webapp subfolder: 
looking at `...\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\File_Demo\1011_1.png`.
I guess (I am not using eclipse myself), that your server is under `org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0`, and your webapp is called `File_Demo`.

so the correct path to the image should be `1011_1.png` only (or `../1011_1.png` if your struts action is inside some package).